# iphone connection with openerp

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipod-touch, odoo

Greetings,

I am thinking of getting an application in iPhone to establish connection with a application server to collects its contact details and then sync it with our address book.

Anyone could direct me in the direction i have to take to achieve this target. And the things i have to look up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone is working on a [mobile client for OpenERP](http://openerpclientmobile.blogspot.com/), but I don't know if there are any plans for iPhone specifically.

If you want to build your own, I suggest you look at the OpenERP developer book's section on [web services](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/index.html#service-base-integration). You can send XML-RPC requests to the server to do anything the regular client can do. The XML-RPC layer is basically a wrapper around the [ORM methods](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html).

Comment: Hi, I have gone through the link you have mentioned but its a closed group in development. I am actually looking for some reference tutorials in the similar area.

Comment: OK, @alanvabraham, I added some links to documentation that might help.

Answer (score 1):

You must, first of all, start with a XML-RPC library for iPhone. That is not implemented yet in the iOS core sdk. A good starting point is the open source application developed from wordpress that contain a xml-rpc library. Then you can play with the method from within this application, calling specific opener methods.

This is the link to download wordpress for iOS: http://ios.wordpress.org/development/